# Sum of the product of a number and user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make this program work?

**Problem**

I need to set how many number of float inputs a user can enter. And then multiply each input by a number and sum each product.

**Code**

```
userInput = int(input("Enter how many numbers you would like to input? "))
numList = [None] * userInput
for x in range(userInput):
    numList[x] = float(input("What is the value of number 1? "))
multiplicand = int(input("Enter the multiplicand: "))
for y in numList:
product = multiplicand * y
sumOfproduct = sum(product)
print(sumOfproduct)
```

**Output should look like:**

Enter how many numbers you would like to input? 3

What is the value of number 1? 2

What is the value of number 2? 3

What is the value of number 3? 1

Enter the multiplicand: 5

The total value is: 30

Comment: Please don't deface your question. Questions here are meant to help out *future visitors* with the same problem, not just you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
userInput = int(input("Enter how many numbers you would like to input? "))
multiplicand = int(input("Enter the multiplicand: "))
ans = 0
for x in range(userInput):
    num = float(input("What is the value of number " + str(x) + " ? "))
    ans += num*multiplicand

print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userInput = int(input("Enter how many numbers you would like to input? "))
numList = [None] * userInput
for x in range(userInput):
    numList[x] = float(input("What is the value of number "+str(x+1)+"?"))
multiplicand = int(input("Enter the multiplicand: "))
l = sum(numList)*multiplicand
print (l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve ur prob :
`

```
temp1 = 1
temp2 = 0
user_input=[]
no_of_input=int(input("Enter how many numbers you would like to input? "))

for i in range(0,no_of_input) :
    num=float(input("enter input {0}".format(i+1)))
    user_input.append(num)

multiplicand=float(input(("enter the multiplicand")))



for j in range(0,no_of_input) :
    temp1=multiplicand * user_input[j]
    temp2= temp2 + temp1



print("total value is {0}".format(temp2))
```

`