# getting the sum of multiple inputs under the same variable

Tags: python, sum

```
while True:
    price = int(input("please enter the price for the product: $"))
    a = input("Do you want to enter another product? (Enter y for yes)")
    if a == "y":
        continue
    elif a == "n":
        total= sum(price)
        print("the total amount for the products is:  $", total)
        
    else:
        print("the input is invalid, please try again (y for yes, n for no) ")
        a = input("Do you want to enter another product? ")
```

to calculate the sum of the price what should I do I tried using the sum command but it caused an error in my code.
the error I got is `Unexpected type(s):(int)Possible type(s):(Iterable)(Iterable)`

Comment: Please, paste the text of the error in a [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code block (see the edits to your original post).

Comment: you can create a variable 'total' before the beginning of the loop and keep on adding the price to the total and display it.

Comment: You could store the inputs in a list using `append()`, or you could calculate the total after each inputted price.

Comment: Unexpected type(s):(int)Possible type(s):(Iterable)(Iterable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of the product of a number and user inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692544/sum-of-the-product-of-a-number-and-user-inputs)

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64086165/15032126) there's a solution using lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, actually. Initialize the `total` variable with 0 outside the loop, and keep on adding `price` to `total`.

```
total = 0
while True:
    price = int(input("please enter the price for the product: $"))
    total = total + price
    a = input("Do you want to enter another product? (Enter y for yes)")
    if a == "y":  
        continue
    elif a == "n":
        print("the total amount for the products is:  $", total)
        
    else:
        print("the input is invalid, please try again (y for yes, n for no) ")
        a = input("Do you want to enter another product? ")
```

Comment: You're very close, but `sum(price)` is incorrect

Comment: And it's simpler to use `+=`, like `total += price`

Comment: Yes. But that could be slightly confusing for beginners,

Answer (score 0):

```
total_price=[]

while True:

    price = int(input("please enter the price for the product: $"))

    a = input("Do you want to enter another product? (Enter y for yes)")

    total_price.append(price)

    if a == "y":
        continue

    elif a == "n":
        total= sum(total_price)
        print("the total amount for the products is:  $", total)
        
    else:
        print("the input is invalid, please try again (y for yes, n for no) ")
        a = input("Do you want to enter another product? ")
```

Comment: just create a list, append all the prices and after getting a "n" get the total by using sum() on total_price list

Comment: Please [edit] to add details, don't use comments

Comment: BTW, I just edited it myself to fix the formatting. Check out the [formatting help page](/editing-help)